# How can I make a keyboard not appear when selecting a text field?

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard, textfield

I'm using a list picker to change the information in the text field so I don't want the keyboard to pop up at all. Is there any way to make it so the keyboard doesn't pop up.

Comment: Make the picker the text field's `inputView`.

Comment: Sorry I'm a nube. How do you do that?

Comment: To do that you can use `yourTextField.inputView = yourPickerView` when setting up in `viewDidLoad()` method.

Comment: I tried that but I got an error. Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```